# Organizing data in mix of comma-separated, tab-separated format

Tags: python, file-io, data-structures

I am a complete newbie in python. It would be great if you can help me. My data format is somewhat like this. I would appreciate if someone can help me out.

```
car    trans  +  1,4,6,8
plane  trans  +  3,5,7,9,4,3
train  trans  -  2,4,6,7
bus    trans  -  1,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Among the comma-separated values, I am trying to extract only the "eventh" numbers (2nd,4th,6th,8th,10th, etc) out and positing it according to + or - value of third column.

I want to place the "eventh" numbers out from the comma-separated data and if it is "+", the number goes to fourth column and add 1 to that value then place it in 5th column. If it is "-", the number goes fifth column and minus 1 to that value and place it in fourth column. I know it is really copmlicated explanation but it would be great if anyone can give me an idea where i can start from. Thanks

```
car.1    trans  +  4  5
car.2    trans  +  8  9
plane.1  trans  +  5  6
plane.2  trans  +  9  10
plane.3  trans  +  3  4
train.1  trans  -  3  4
train.2  trans  -  6  7
bus.1    trans  -  2  3
bus.2    trans  -  4  5
bus.3    trans  -  6  7
```

edit2: so after a lot of searching and help from you guys, I now have something like this. This gives me the proper output but my only problem now is that I am having trouble naming it right. (ie. car.1, car.2,car.3, plane.1,plane.2 .... etc) Can someone give me insight into this problem?

```
import sys
import string
infileName = sys.argv[1]
outfileName = sys.argv[2]

def getGenes(infile, outfile):

infile = open(infileName,"r")
outfile = open(outfileName, "w")

while 1:
    line = infile.readline()
    if not line: break
    wrds = string.split(line)
    comma = string.split(wrds[3], ",")
    print(comma)
    fivess = comma[1::2]
    print(fivess)

    if len(wrds) >= 2:
        name = wrds[0]
        chr = wrds[1]
        type = wrds[2]
        print(type)
    if type == "+":
        for jj in fivess:
            start = jj
            stop = string.atoi(jj)+1
            outfile.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' %(name, chr, type, start, stop))           
    elif type == "-":
        for jj in fivess:
            stop = jj
            start= string.atoi(jj)-1
            outfile.write('%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' %(name, chr, type, start, stop))   



 getGenes(infileName, outfileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split each line by the tab; then split the last item (the list of numbers) on the comma.  That'll give you all of the bits to do your processing with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split method in order to do it:

```
txt = """car    trans  +  1,4,6,8
plane  trans  +  3,5,7,9,4,3
train  trans  -  2,4,6,7
bus    trans  -  1,3,4,5,6,7,8"""
lines = txt.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    vehicle,vehicle_type,action,numbers = line.split('\t')
    numbers_list = numbers.split(',')
```

You can get only the even numbers from a list by:

```
even_locations_list = numbers_list[1::2] #starting from position 1 (the second object) and jumping 2 steps at a time)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of **split** splits on any whitespace (spaces, tabs, what have you).

```
with open('infile.txt','r') as infile, open('outfile.txt','w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        name, group, op, elements = line.split()
        elements = [int(i) for i in elements.split(',')[1::2]]
        for idx, val in enumerate(elements):
            if op == '-':
                col4, col5 = val - 1, val
            else:
                col4, col5 = val, val + 1
            output = "\t".join(map(str,
                        ["{}.{}".format(name, idx+1), group, op, col4, col5]))
            outfile.write(output + "\n")
```

Comment: I couldnt get it working but I ended up with something like above. I am not sure how to make the names go car.1 car.2 plane.1 plane.2 and etc. Can you give me suggestion based on my edit?